# string modifiers and properties do not work

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to use `Methods` and `Properties` of the `String Class` to modify a string, but I keep getting an Invalid qualifier compile error. I even copied the following code* directly from the MSDN website and it throws the same error.

```
Public Sub Main()
    Dim original As String
    original = "aaabbb"
    Dim modified As String
    modified = original.Insert(3, " ")
End Sub

'This is the original code, but I had to change it slightly because the word-vba
'programming environment didn't like the syntax and highlighted everything red.

'Public Sub Main()
   'Dim original As String = "aaabbb"
   'Console.WriteLine("The original string: '{0}'", original)
   'Dim modified As String = original.Insert(3, " ")
   'Console.WriteLine("The modified string: '{0}'", modified)
'End Sub
```

Does word-vba not support string class modifiers and properties, am I not initializing the string correctly, or is there some other problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> modified = original.Insert(3, " ")
> ```

You're thinking in VB.NET, but writing VBA. Strings (or any primitive or UDT type) don't have members in VBA. Not your fault, finding official VBA documentation is getting harder every day, with every "VBA" search yielding results for VB.NET.

That original code is clearly VB.NET.

If you mean to concatenate 3 spaces in front of `original`, then what you want to do is this:

```
modified = String(3, " ") & original
```

If you mean to get *a new string in which a specified string is inserted at a specified index position in this instance* ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=vs.110).aspx)), then you want to do this (thanks @A.S.H!):

```
modified = Left$(original, 3) & " " & Right$(original, Len(original) - 3)
```

Comment: I am actually trying to use the `.Chars` and `.Insert` methods along with the `.Length` property to go through a string and add spaces in certain positions given a set of criteria. However, the code is a little long so I decided to use the code from MSDN because was simple and was theoretically supposed to work. Are there ways to read characters from a string and modify a string in VBA?

Comment: The code on MSDN is for another language, it won't work in VBA. There's no `.Chars`, `.Insert` or `.Length` member for a string in VBA. You use functions from the `VBA.Strings` module instead, which you can browse using the *Object Browser* (F2).